# Simple query laravel 4 table and pivot table output

Tags: database, laravel, pivot, eloquent

I believe this should be really simple but for some reason it's not.

I have tables

```
student 
|id|name|...etc

school
|id|name|....etc

school_student
|id|school_id|student_id
```

Student Model

```
public function schools()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('School');
}
```

School Model

```
public function students(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Student');
}
```

I would simply like to output students who belong to school_id=1 for example.

In other words:

```
    SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN school_student ON student.id=school_student.student_id WHERE school_id='1'
```

Using Laravel 4.1 . I'm fairly new to Laravel and maybe I have a mental blocks on this but have not managed to find a solution that works.

I tried several ways but  all wrong. The basic without the school_id search is:

```
      $students = Student::with('schools')->get();
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: What is your model called?

Comment: I have update question to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably got a School model which should have a method like this...

```
public function students(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Student');
}
```

Then you can do

```
$school = School::with('students')->find($id);
var_dump($school->students());
```

Comment: The view output is empty. I have checked the table again and there is a school_student record id=1,student_id=7,school_id=1 and also student record id=7 and school record id=1

Comment: This also goes through all the user tables throttle etc...[{"query":"select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1","bindings":["25"],"time":0.69},{"query":"select * from `throttle` where `user_id` = ? limit 1"....

Comment: Though I'm still concerned that this seems to run through a lot of queries.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways depending on your needs:

using ORM relations:

```
// 1st query to fetch school, 2nd query to fecth the students
$school = School::find($shoolId);
$school->students; // Collection of related students

// 1 query with joins
Student::whereHas('school', function ($q) use ($schoolId) {
   $q->where('schools.id', $schoolId);
})->get();
```

using manual joins:

```
// 1 query with join
Student::join('school_student as ss', function ($q) use ($schoolId) {
   $q->on('ss.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
     ->where('ss.school_id', '=', $schoolId);
})->get();
```

---

Answering one of your comments: `find` and `get` are different, first will return single model or `null`, latter will return collection always.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading, the "Eager Load Constraints" Section tells you what you need

here a example for your situation

```
 $students = Student::with('schools', function($query){
          $query->where('school_id', '=', 1);
 })->get();
```

Comment: I did try this with an array, and it didn't work. Yours gives this error : explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Comment: where you used the array? on where('school_id', '=', ARRAY) ?

Comment: For yours I did exactly as posted and it didn't work. I tried this before that **$users = $students = Student::with(array('school' => function($query)
{$query->where('school_id', '=', '1');
}))->get();** as per laravel docs